# How to return atom/xml feed from github API

Tags: javascript, api

I'm fetching the public feed from the github API which is in atom/xml format. However all I can seem to get is the url and none of the data.

I've tried requesting different content in the fetch header, but it always comes back as json. The endpoint just displays the URL and I'm not sure how to pull that data from that URL to display it in my application.

```
fetch("https://api.github.com/feeds", {
    mode: 'cors',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml'
    }})
  .then((res) => {
    console.log(res);
    return res.json();

  })
  .then((data) => {
    console.log(data._links.timeline.href);
    console.log(data);
    // this.setState( {feed: text});
    return data;
  })
```

Comment: `'Content-Type': 'application/atom+xml'` is nonsense. You are making a GET request, there is no request body to describe the type of.

Comment: How are you running that JS anyway? If I run it in a browser it errors with "blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check". And `fetch` isn't a Node.js built-in so it won't run there without extra code (in which case setting the mode to cors would be pointless since Node.js doesn't care about it).

Comment: It's a local React application at the moment. I'm running a node dev server on my machine. Thanks for pointing that out about the headercontent. I'm still confused as how to pull the actual feed from that link. I can pull the actual link and when I click it it takes me to the RSS feeds, but I want to dynamically display the feed directly in my application.